# Disabling lmodern in rmarkdown

Tags: latex, r-markdown, pdflatex

R_markdown can't compile my code in pdf-file, because package lmodern doesn't like cyrillic symbols. Could I disable lmodern in the header of rmarkdown and how if i could? This doesn't help:

```
    ---
    title: "«Ластовецкий Дмитрий_ДКР2_ПСА-3"
    author: "Ластовецкий Дмитрий"
    date: "08 06 2021"
    output:
      pdf_document: 
        extra_dependencies:
         lmodern: NULL
    header-includes:
       - \usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
       - \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    lang: ru-RU
    ---
# Задание 1:

Для задачи классификации я решил выбрать датасет, использованный маркетологами банков Португалии. Описание всех оригинальных переменных можно прочитать на кэггл (https://www.kaggle.com/sonujha090/bank-marketing) Приведу описания только тех переменных, что пригодились мне в ходе исследования (после моих преобразований, замены строчных данных на binary), а также верхнюю часть итоговой таблицы данных:
```

The error now is:

```
! Font T2A/cmr/m/n/10=larm1000 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not fo
und.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.112 ...\familydefault\seriesdefault\shapedefault

! name = larm1000, rootname = larm, pointsize = 1000
! mktexmf: empty or non-existent rootfile!

! mktexmf: empty or non-existent rootfile!

! kpathsea: Running mktexmf larm1000.mf

! The command name is C:\Users\79671\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32\mktexmf
! Cannot find larm1000.mf.

! Cannot find larm1000.mf.

! kpathsea: Running mktextfm larm1000

! The command name is C:\Users\79671\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32\mktextfm

! kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
```

In TeXStudio errors are:

```
line 112: Font T2A/cmr/m/n/10=larm1000 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found. ...\familydefault\seriesdefault\shapedefault
line 539: Font T2A/lmr/m/n/10=larm1000 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found. ...andafter\ifx\the\font\nullfont\normalfont
line 76: Missing \begin{document}. \nobreakspace
line 1161: Package babel Error: Unknown option 'russian'. Either you misspelled itd. \ExecuteOptions{\bbl@opt@main}
line 1163: Package babel Error: Unknown option 'russian'. Either you misspelled itd. \ProcessOptions*
line 95: pdfTeX error (font): invalid font identifier. \begin{document}
line 112: Font shape `T2A/lmr/m/n' undefined(Font) using `T2A/cmr/m/n' instead
: No file Ластовецкий_ДКР2_ПСА-3.aux.
```

Comment: Can you make a [mre] that reproduces your problem with lmodern? Maybe you could just load a package which supports cyrillic after lmodern?

Comment: You could also trick latex and make it believe lmodern is already loaded, but again, this requires a [mre] to see how to best integrate this into your document

Comment: Please edit your question. As you can see, comments don't support line breaks

Comment: just edit question itself

Comment: As far as i can see just T2A package supports cyrillic

Comment: Sorry this is my first question here............

Comment: Your example compiles fine for me with or without the `lmodern` package (lmodern does not have all the font shapes, but it will automatically fall back to computer modern)

Comment: What version of rmarkdwn do you have? As i know, it worked good with old rmarkdown, but doesn't work with the latest version that i have

Comment: That's not a markdown problem, but that your tinytex can't generate the necessary font files (I'm not a tinytex user, but use texlive myself, so no idea what the problem might be)

Comment: Thank you! Will try to compile TeX using texstudio

Comment: Can you add `keep_tex: true` to your header and show the resulting .tex file? Then I could do a quick test and completely rule out a markdown problem.

Comment: I'm waiting, it tries to update `tlmgr`

Comment: updated original post

Comment: I always suggest using HTML and then printing to PDF as a work flow suggestion.

Comment: @Dmitry Ok, looks like you get the same errors if you compile the tex file directly in texstudio. If you take rmarkdown completely out  the question, you should be able to ask at https://tex.stackexchange.com about this strange behaviour of your tex distribution (but don't show the incomplete error lines from texstudio, but instead show your .log file).